# Jquery autocomplete not working on localhost

Tags: tomcat, jquery-autocomplete

I got a Spring 3 application with JQuery autocomplete  which works on the outside server, but not on my localhost. I'm using TomCat 6. Anyone know how to configure it in order to work?

Comment: I don't really think it is the code, because it works in other environment.

Comment: What is the source of your autocomplete? Are you requesting info from the same server that your page is hosted, or when running on localhost are you requesting data from the outside server?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that it is not a cross-site domain issue.

Or try [JSONP data type in AJAX request](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote-jsonp.html), which accepts cross site domain requests